# How to call to a class object at the class itself?

Tags: python, class

I'm new at Python and I'm trying to do something and hope you can help me:
If I'm defining a class at Python like: `class foo:`, and inside the class I want to do something with "foo" object, i.e. - I want that one of the objects of the class will be something like `a=foo()`.

So, it should look like:

```
 class foo:
     def __init__(self):
         self.t=7

     a=foo() #it's outside init....
```

It is possible?
There is a way to do it?
*(I'm trying to do this and it's always give me errors...)*
*(I tried to do `import` to the file but it doesn't help at all...)*

Thank you!

Comment: You need to create a function in class, and then you may do it within the function

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri - it's working! Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to write a Singleton pattern? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python

Comment: @ziggyjones - no.....

Answer (score 1):

Do it after the class definition:

```
class Foo:
    pass

Foo.a = Foo()
```

Comment: Yes, it's an attribute of the class, just as if you had defined it in the class definition.

Comment: `NameError: name 'foo' is not defined`

Comment: Ah yeah, you musta caught my answer in the brief window while I had that typo in it.  As to your other comment, yeah, it's part of the class; see for yourself!

Answer (score 0):

No. at the stage you define `a = foo`, foo is not defined. However, you can create a variable for foo instance inside foo like:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  a = None

Foo.a = Foo()
```

edited according to the comments.

Comment: That won't work. The instance `a` will shadow the class `a`.

Comment: where is the class `a` ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not actually needed for this purpose, but without it one cannot call Foo.a before doing `Foo.a = Foo()`.

Comment: Of course you can. `class Foo: pass; Foo.a = Foo()` is perfectly valid Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, but I mean you cannot do things like `if isinstance(Foo.a, Foo)`.

Comment: Well, you could use error handling, but why is that relevant?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not perfectly relevant. You can say it is an unnecessary personal practice.

Comment: I think you meant to write `a = None` inside the class definition. Doing it on an instance variable (`self.a`) wouldn't let you access `Foo.a` before assigning a value.

Comment: @interjay You are correct. It is an error. Thank you!

Comment: It still wouldn't work (it would gave an error because `self` doesn't exist). I edited it to something that does work.

Comment: @interjay Yes, it was a typo. Thank you for the editing!