# How to construct inner class from within static outer class

Tags: python

I have a static base class, which I want to encapsulate child classes. I cannot find the syntax to create the inner classes from within a static outer class.

Here's an example of what I want:

```
class Farm:
    my_pet_cat = Animal("Meeeeooowww", "Fluffy")

    class Animal:            
        def __init__(self, sound, fur):
            self.sound = sound
            self.fur = fur

        def speak(self):
            print(self.sound)

        def pet(self):
            return self.fur
```

> NameError: name 'Animal' is not defined

I tried accessing `Animal` with `self.Animal(...)` but this didn't work, as obviously `Farm` doesn't have a self, being a static class and all. I also successfully accessed `Animal` if it is placed outside of `Farm`, but I want to encapsulate the `Animal` class within the `Farm` class.

Can this be done??

Comment: There's no such thing as an "inner class" in Python. You don't typically need any.

Comment: Why do you need inner class at all? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want `Farm` to be a container of `Animal` objects or do you want it to be base class of `Animal`? Or something else? Anyway... your code would work if you put line `my_pet_cat = Animal("Meeeeooowww", "Fluffy")` **after** definition of `Animal`.

Comment: I am just hiding this stuff away. `Farm` is going to be available to the rest of the application - but `Animal` and other inner classes I want to be more "hidden", so I am encapsulating them within `Farm`. In my actual application it is used for UI Menus and Menu Items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define Animal class before you reference it to create an instance.

```
class Farm:
    class Animal:            
        def __init__(self, sound, fur):
            self.sound = sound
            self.fur = fur

        def speak(self):
            print(self.sound)

        def pet(self):
            return self.fur

    my_pet_cat = Animal("Meeeeooowww", "Fluffy")
```

Comment: this answers the actual question, but it's quite likely that `my_pet_cat` should be an instance variable instantiated in `__init__` rather than a class variable.

Comment: @MatthewStory, in my case it's fine. I want it to be a singleton kind of pattern.

Comment: @ChickenFeet this is a pretty weird way to do a singleton in python. The standard approches to doing that are covered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons ... the top 3 answers are what you typically see.

Comment: @MatthewStory okay thanks, I'll have a look :)
I am trying to force a bit more structure into python, coming from C#.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a module named Farm and in the `Farm` module, define a class name `Animal`?

Comment: The module is `farm` which has a class `Farm`. I am trying to hide away the classes in `Farm` so the rest of the application doesn't get crowded. Perhaps there isn't a need for this, since you can import individual classes from a module - but it's done now :p